# Storybook call function which is a prop of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I have a component "Item" and a container. The container has a lazy Loading function, with which I load the items. So I have to trigger that function, to display the items. How can I trigger the function in storybook?

```
// Container.js with Item component
        <Item
          key={post.id}
          lazyLoading={this.lazyloading.bind(this)} //I need to trigger this function, to load the posts     
          text={this.props.text}
          styles={this.props.styles}
        />



// Item.stories.js
    let key = 1;
    let text = "test";
    let styles = { 
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
    storiesOf('Item', module).add(
  'default',
  (() => (
    <Item
      key={key}
      text={text}
      styles={styles}
      lazyLoadingImage={} // How can I call this function? 
    />
  ))
);
```